# How can I have a function that matches and replaces parts of a string in C#

Tags: c#

I have web page HTML code such as the following:

```
<html>
<div class="code" id="one">
<pre>
      int i = 1;
      int j = 2;
</pre>
</div>
<h1>Sample heading</h1>
<div class="code" id="two">
<pre>
      int i = 1;
      int j = 2;
</pre>
</div>
```

The code is in a C# string and what I need to do is to find some way to replace the `<pre>` areas with something like this:

```
<table>
<tr><td>1</td><td><code>   int i = 1</code></td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td><code>   int j = 2</code></td></tr>
</table>
```

How can I take the original string and make a new string that consists of the original data but with some function to convert the `<pre>` text that is applied to the `<pre>` text areas?

Comment: You probably want to use some sort of XSLT transform: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT

Comment: These articles explain how to do XSLT transforms in .NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14689742.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If I was you, I'd use some form of XML parser to locate the `<pre>` elements.

```
    XDocument loDoc = XDocument.Parse(lcHTML);

    foreach (XElement loElement in loDoc.Descendants("pre"))
    {
        //-- Modify the html to your heart's content.
        //-- You can split the html on newline character, prefix each line with your table stuff along with the line index. Then write the XML back out.
    }
```